# Mysql cross table join

Tags: mysql

hi i have 2 mysql table as follow:

items

```
id item_name user_id
1    test1     1    
2    test2     1
3    test3     1
4    test4     1
```

project

```
id user_id items
1    1       1,3
2    1       2,4
```

how can write a join query that can return each items in a project?

```
project1 =>
    item1=>
      [id1] =>
      [name1] =>
    item3=>
      [id3] =>
      [name3] =>
```

Thanks.

UPDATE
item tbl
[image]

project tbl
[image]

Comment: What type does the `items` attribute have?

Comment: why would u add items as comma separated values in project table?

Comment: If you could create 3rd table project_item it would be much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all** don't store strings of delimited values in your db. You're limiting your self with the means to normally maintain and query data. Normalize your data (in this case by introducing `project_items` table with `project_id` and `item_id` columns). It'll pay off big time in a long run.

In the mean time you can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to join your tables

```
SELECT p.id project_id, p.user_id, i.id item_id, i.item_name 
   FROM project p LEFT JOIN items i
     ON FIND_IN_SET(i.id, p.items) > 0
    AND p.user_id = i.user_id
 ORDER BY p.id, i.id
```

Output:

```
| PROJECT_ID | USER_ID | ITEM_ID | ITEM_NAME |
----------------------------------------------
|          1 |       1 |       1 |     test1 |
|          1 |       1 |       3 |     test3 |
|          2 |       1 |       2 |     test2 |
|          2 |       1 |       4 |     test4 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a66b/7)** demo

**UPDATE:** Values of `items` should not contain spaces. Either remove them or use `REPLACE()` like this

```
    ON FIND_IN_SET(i.id, REPLACE(p.items, ' ', '')) > 0
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54eb8/5)** demo

Comment: @zlippr Just add it to join condition. I've updated the answer and sqlfiddle example to reflect that.

Comment: but i am only getting one result..why it's so? this is query SELECT p.id project_id, i.id ,i.item_name FROM jr5t3_jblance_project p JOIN jr5t3_jblance_item i ON FIND_IN_SET(i.id, p.items) > 0 ORDER BY p.id, i.id

Comment: See updated answer. Use `LEFT JOIN` and `p.user_id = i.user_id` condition

Comment: for better sample look at update i made on question, do you think this query will fetch exactly like how sql demo can fetch?

Comment: it's only returning 1 result instead 2

Comment: @zlippr Your problem is that you have spaces between delimited values. Here is **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54eb8/1)** that illustrates it. Remove all spaces and maintain it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not good. You have to create a relational table between items and projects. Including the list of values ​​followed by commas in a record is not a good idea.

You should create an additional table relational called: project_items

and you can use the following sentence to retrieve the items from a project

```
select project_items.id_project, items.item_name, items.user_id 
from project_items 
left join items on project_items.id_item = items.id
```

That's a better approach